# JQuery ContextMenu not work in multiple id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have div-> id ids that when I right-click I display a window, when a simple click gets the data, but when I right click through $.contextMenu for the first time, that data is maintained for all div->id.

```
          $('.w_content').click(function (e){
              e.preventDefault();
              var wor = $( e.target ).attr('id');
              console.log(wor);
              $.contextMenu({
                selector: '.wcontext',
                callback: function(key, options) {
                    // console.log(wor);
                  $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
                  $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url()?>documentos/getDocDetalleAjax',
                    data: {id: dat.id_documento,orden:wor},
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function ( msg ){
                      console.log(msg);
                      // if (typeof msg[index] == 'undefined' || msg[index] == null) {
                      //   console.log('sisis');
                      // }
                      // var wd = $.parseJSON ( msg );
                      // $('#dtitulo').val(wd.titulo);
                      // console.log(msg);
                    }
                  });
                },
                items: {
                    "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
                    "sep1": "---------",
                    "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: function(){
                        return 'context-menu-icon context-menu-icon-quit';
                    }}
                }
              });

            });
```

The id is within the class = ".w_content"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same `id` on different elements? An `id` attribute value is meant to be unique. If you have multiple elements with the same `id` you're going to start running in to JavaScript, CSS and possibly even HTML problems. Use CSS classes if you want to target multiple elements.

Comment: No, id is generated with:  html + = '<p id = "' + i + '" class = "wcontext">'; html + = '</ p>'; in loop.